# Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on skylake with Nvidia GeForce 930MX

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my new laptop ( Asus R558u - i5 6th generation with Nvidia GeForce 930MX), it is working perfectly fine.
After installation of Ubuntu, to install Nvidia drivers, I have changed the settings to use proprietary drivers, to make the changes live I had to modify grub file from

```
"quiet splash"
```

to

```
"quiet splash pci=nomsi"
```

After doing so, I am not able to use GUI on kernel 4.4.0.36(generic) so I have to change to 4.4.0.31 (generic). Kindly help out.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu 16.10 as it is working perfectly on R558UR (I have the same model). After installation, add this line in your grub:

```
"quiet splash pci=noaer"
```

Save, then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot, then run this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-367
```

(Version 367 is the latest driver as of this date). Then blacklist `nouveau` by this method:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Go to the end of the file and add this line: `blacklist nouveau`. Save and exit.
After rebooting, you can see the `nvidia X server Settings` icon in menu, which will let you switch between integrated 520 and discrete 930MX graphics (You need to log out and then log in again to switch cards).

Comment: Fresh install or update will work.?

Comment: Don't know about update, I fresh installed it.